# Compare one datatable's rows to another datatable's columns

Tags: c#, datatable

```
first table:dtHeader
 Header
---------
Address
ZipCode
city
state


Second table:-dtReport

RowNumber-----Address------Zipcode---Region------city

   1200       JC           00000     NYC         Bronx

   13000       RC            12345    NC          Boston
```

I want to remove all columns in dtreport where columnname is not in dtHeader
So the result dtReport will have Address--zipcode--city columns only.
I dont want to create another datatable as it has large number of rows i.e 70000
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have already written something or are you completely stuck on this?

Comment: I am completely stuck on this. Either it removes all the columns or it removes the required columns but not the unwanted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Except` to find all column-names that must be removed from `dtReport`

```
var notAllowedColNames = dtReport.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Select(c=> c.ColumnName.ToUpperInvariant())
    .Except(dtHeader.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<String>("Header").ToUpperInvariant()))
    .ToList();
foreach(var colName in notAllowedColNames) 
     dtReport.Columns.Remove(colName);
```

I have used `ToUpperInvariant` since `ZipCode` has a different case in both tables.

Comment: This one works like charm....Its really Magic...I was stuck on this since long time! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but a simple loop on the dtReport columns collection checking if dtHeader columns collection contains a equal named column. If not remove the column from dtReport.

```
    SqlCommand cmdHeader = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Header", conn);
    SqlCommand cmdReport = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Report", conn);
    DataTable dtHeader = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtReport = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdHeader);
    da1.Fill(dtHeader)
    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdReport);
    da2.Fill(dtReport);

    for(int x = dtReport.Columns.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        DataColumn dc = dtReport.Columns[x];
        if(!dtHeader.Columns.Contains(dc.ColumnName))
             dtReport.Columns.Remove(dc.ColumnName);
    }
```

The trick is to use a for..loop going from the last column to the first. In this way you could remove the column while iterating over the collection (foreach cannot do this)

Comment: Thank you. I used for each loop and that's where I was stuck. I will try this. The header table is generated c# and not from database while the report table is from database !

Comment: Hey I tried your solution but it did not work like the way I wanted. But thank you so much for helping me. I was really stuck on this since long time. Thank you.

Comment: @Steve: why do think that a database is involved?

Comment: @TimSchmelter probably it is a mental habit of mine, when I see a variable that start with dt I think to a DataTable

Comment: @Steve: yes, of course there are [`DataTables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataTable(v=vs.110).aspx) as OP has mentioned in the qustion. But a `DataTable` is just an in-memory collection of data, they can be filled from anywhere, a database is not necessary. Actually OP asked how to remove the columns from an existing and filled table, that's why i was a little bit suprised to see two sql answers.

Answer (score 0):

An all SQL answer would look like this

```
    INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE
  SELECT c.name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE t.name = 'dtReport' AND c.name NOT IN (SELECT Header FROM dtHeader)

  WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP_TABLE) > 0)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT TOP 1 Header FROM #TEMP_TABLE)
        ALTER TABLE PATRON DROP COLUMN @COLUMN_NAME
        DELETE FROM #TEMP_TABLE WHERE Header = @COLUMN_NAME
    END
```